# How to speed up nested loops for groupby multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, performance, vectorization, multi-index

I have two Multiindex dataframes, namely, panel1 and panel2: both have the same level 0 index-the dates, but different level 1 index; see sample code below:

```
# panel1:
idx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['2017-05-02', '2017-05-03', '2017-05-04'],['id1', 'id2', 'id3']],names=['Dates', 'id'])
panel1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(9,2), index=idx1,columns=['ytm','mat'])
# panel2:
idx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['2017-05-02', '2017-05-03', '2017-05-04'],['0.5', '1.5', '2.5']],names=['Dates', 'yr'])
panel2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(9), index=idx2,columns=['curve'])
```

I want to loop over the two panels by the Dates (level 0 index). So for each day (e.g. '2017-05-02'), I search the **mat** of each id/row (of panel1) in the **yr** column (of panel2), if there is a match, I want to get the corresponding **curve** values (of panel2) and add it as a new column (named **CDB**) in panel1.

My current code as following:

```
group1=panel1.groupby(level=0)
group2=panel2.groupby(level=0)

lst=[]
for ytm in group1:              # loop over each day
    for yr in group2:           # loop over each day
        df_ytm=ytm[1]           # get df of id, yt & mat
        df_ytm=df_ytm.assign(CDB=np.nan)      # add a col of nan, later will be replaced by matched curve values
        df_curve=yr[1].reset_index()          # need get rid of index to match yr with t_mat
        df_curve.yr=df_curve.yr.astype(float) 
        for i in range(df_ytm.shape[0]):      # loop over each row
            if (df_ytm.iloc[i,1]==df_curve.yr).any()==True:      # search if each 'mat' value in 'yr' column
                df_ytm.iloc[i,2]=df_curve[df_curve.yr.isin([df_ytm.t_mat[i]])].curve.values   # if matched, set 'CDB' as curve value
    lst.append(df_ytm)      # need get modified 'df_ytm' (with matched 'CDB')
```

The code works as I tried with a small sample, but I have a huge panel 1 (sized 800 days times 10000 ids) and big panel 2 as well. So the code has been running for more than 24 hours.

I wonder how could I rewrite the code (use possible vectorization) to speed it up?

Any comments would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need to construct new `MultiIndex` from `Dates` index and `mat` column and get values of `curve` for this index.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(12)
idx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [["2017-05-02", "2017-05-03", "2017-05-04"], ["id1", "id2", "id3"]],
    names=["Dates", "id"],
)
panel1 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(3, size=(9, 2)), index=idx1, columns=["ytm", "mat"]
)
idx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [["2017-05-02", "2017-05-03", "2017-05-04"], ["0", "1", "2"]], names=["Dates", "yr"]
)
panel2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size=9), index=idx2, columns=["curve"])
print(panel1)
#                 ytm  mat
# Dates      id
# 2017-05-02 id1    2    1
#            id2    1    2
#            id3    0    0
# 2017-05-03 id1    2    1
#            id2    0    1
#            id3    1    1
# 2017-05-04 id1    2    2
#            id2    2    0
#            id3    1    0
print(panel2)
#                curve
# Dates      yr
# 2017-05-02 0       0
#            1       1
#            2       2
# 2017-05-03 0       1
#            1       2
#            2       0
# 2017-05-04 0       1
#            1       2
#            2       0
panel1["CDM"] = panel2.loc[
    pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
        [panel1.index.get_level_values(0), panel1.mat.astype(str).rename("yr")]
    )
].to_numpy()
print(panel1)
#                 ytm  mat  CDM
# Dates      id
# 2017-05-02 id1    2    1    1
#            id2    1    2    2
#            id3    0    0    0
# 2017-05-03 id1    2    1    2
#            id2    0    1    2
#            id3    1    1    2
# 2017-05-04 id1    2    2    0
#            id2    2    0    1
#            id3    1    0    1
```

**EDIT**

To compare `mat` and `yr` as float and to use `.reindex` instead of `.loc`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(12)
idx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [["2017-05-02", "2017-05-03", "2017-05-04"], ["id1", "id2", "id3"]],
    names=["Dates", "id"],
)
panel1 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(3, size=(9, 2)), index=idx1, columns=["ytm", "mat"]
)
panel1.iloc[0, 1] = np.nan
idx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [["2017-05-02", "2017-05-03", "2017-05-04"], ["0", "1", "2"]], names=["Dates", "yr"]
)
panel2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size=9), index=idx2, columns=["curve"])
panel2 = panel2.rename(float, level=1)
print(panel1)
#                 ytm  mat
# Dates      id
# 2017-05-02 id1    2  NaN
#            id2    1  2.0
#            id3    0  0.0
# 2017-05-03 id1    2  1.0
#            id2    0  1.0
#            id3    1  1.0
# 2017-05-04 id1    2  2.0
#            id2    2  0.0
#            id3    1  0.0
print(panel2)
#                 curve
# Dates      yr
# 2017-05-02 0.0      0
#            1.0      1
#            2.0      2
# 2017-05-03 0.0      1
#            1.0      2
#            2.0      0
# 2017-05-04 0.0      1
#            1.0      2
#            2.0      0
panel1["CDM"] = panel2.reindex(
    pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
        [panel1.index.get_level_values(0), panel1.mat.rename("yr")]
    )
).to_numpy()
print(panel1)
#                 ytm  mat  CDM
# Dates      id
# 2017-05-02 id1    2  NaN  NaN
#            id2    1  2.0  2.0
#            id3    0  0.0  0.0
# 2017-05-03 id1    2  1.0  2.0
#            id2    0  1.0  2.0
#            id3    1  1.0  2.0
# 2017-05-04 id1    2  2.0  0.0
#            id2    2  0.0  1.0
#            id3    1  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: Many thanks for the solution! It seems working but with one issue emerged from the code ```panel1.mat.astype(str)```. Since the ```panel1.mat``` is float data with 2 decimal places (e.g. 3.60) which set deliberately to match with the ```panel2.yr``` (float with 2 decimal points), therefore, ```panel1.mat.astype(str)``` convert 3.60 into 3.6 which can't matched as it format as (3.60)  in ```panel2.yr```. I wonder if there are better methods to deal with this? Or need to format panel2.yr. @V.Ayrat

Comment: Just to follow up, there is also a Future Warning returned "__main__:2: FutureWarning: 
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.". I wonder if this would be an issue?

Comment: I think to use float format is better. You can do `panel2 = panel2.rename(float, level=1)`. But this raise the question of comparision of float numbers. If the same values were assigned to `yr` and `mat` the exact match will work, but if there is some intermediate calculation this can slightly change this values and they will not match... If there are missing values then it is better to use `.reindex()` as it suggest to suppress warning.

Comment: I wonder how could I use the```.reindex``` properly in this case? The ```mat``` column has ```nan``` indeed, but ```yr``` with no missing data. Thanks again!

Comment: I suppose ```panel1.mat.astype(str)``` raise the mismatch when ```mat``` format as float (e.g. 3.60) but ```yr``` format as string (e.g. 3.6)...?  In short, I tried to set ```yr``` as float; it leads to all level Multiindex not matching, therefore, make the original suggestion not working...Instead, set ```yr``` as float first and set it as str again, the matching process worked. Also, I wonder how could I properly use ```.reindex``` here? @V.Ayrat

Comment: @G.mc yes `mat` and `yr` should have the same type. To compare them as float `.astype(str)` should be dropped from `panel1.mat.astype(str).rename('yr')`. I updated the answer to reflect this change and `.reindex()` instead of `.loc[]`.

Comment: This makes perfect sense! Your edited code runs with no warning at all, but when I applied it to my datasets: "__main__:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead" showed up. Is this due to the package version I am using? However, the use of ```.iloc[]``` returned me expected results too, if the Future Warning would not cause errors in the matching, maybe is ok to go for that option I suppose. @V.Ayrat

Comment: This one line of code works like a charm! Many thanks! @V.Ayrat

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate any non-empty and repeatable result of my code,
I changed a little the way how both panels are created:

```
np.random.seed(0)
idx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['2017-05-02', '2017-05-03', '2017-05-04'],
    ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']], names=['Dates', 'id'])
panel1 = pd.DataFrame({'ytm': np.random.randn(9),
    'mat': [0.5, 0.82, 1.06, -0.27, 1.5, 0.59, 0.62, 1.89, 2.5]}, index=idx1)
idx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['2017-05-02', '2017-05-03', '2017-05-04'],
    [0.5, 1.5, 2.5]], names=['Dates', 'yr'])
panel2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(9), index=idx2, columns=['curve'])
```

The changes comprise:

- `np.random.seed` - te get repatable results.
- Only *ytm* column of *panel1* is created as random numbers. In order
  to have some matching values in *mat*, I put predefined values there,
  providing one match with *yr* for each date.
- Level 1 of *idx2* is of **float** type. Your sample includes **strings**,
  which obviously will not be equal to *mat* values.

I also suppose that for each group from *panel1* the look for match should
be performed in rows from *panel2* with **the same date** (not in
groups for all dates).

To generate the result (*CDB* column), proceed as follows:

1. Define a function generating *CDB* column for the current group of
   rows (for each date):

   ```
    def getCDB(grp):
        cdb = panel2.xs(grp.index[0][0], level=0).reindex(grp.mat).curve
        return pd.Series(cdb.values, index=grp.index)
   ```
2. Then apply it and save the result in a new column:

   ```
    panel1['CDB'] = panel1.groupby(level=0).apply(getCDB)\
        .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
   ```

For my input data, the result is:

```
                     ytm   mat       CDB
Dates      id                           
2017-05-02 id1  1.764052  0.50  0.410599
           id2  0.400157  0.82       NaN
           id3  0.978738  1.06       NaN
2017-05-03 id1  2.240893 -0.27       NaN
           id2  1.867558  1.50  0.121675
           id3 -0.977278  0.59       NaN
2017-05-04 id1  0.950088  0.62       NaN
           id2 -0.151357  1.89       NaN
           id3 -0.103219  2.50 -0.205158
```